# Record passed from force:recordData to Apex controller method is null

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am using Lightning Data Services to have the current record already prefetched

```
<aura:component controller="MyCtrl" implements="force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="parent" type="SObject" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      fields="Name,..."
                      targetRecord="{!v.parent}"
                      layoutType="FULL" />

   {!v.market.fields.Name.value} <-- WORKS!
</aura:component>
```

I can directly display its fields in the component without any problems. But when I pass the record

```
({
    init: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.queryData");
        action.setParams({ parent: cmp.get("v.parent") });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            ...
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);   
    },
})
```

into my Apex init method fields are not accessible anymore

```
public class MyCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String queryData(Parent__c parent) {
         // parent is null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

force:recordData loads the data asynchronously. This means it won't be available in the init method. Instead, listen for a change event and then get your data:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.parent}" action="{!c.loadChildData}" />
```

---

```
loadChildData: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.queryData");
    action.setParams({ parent: component.get("v.parent") });
    action.setCallback(...);
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

---

The layout for the force:recordData object doesn't align well with the default layout, and the Locker Service Proxy tends to muck things up. Here's an example I finally got working in my org:

```
change: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.queryData"), account = component.get("v.account"), param;
    param = { sobjectType: 'Account', Id: account.fields.Id.value, Name: account.fields.Name.value };
    action.setParams({ record: param });
    console.log(param);
    action.setCallback(this, function(result) { console.log(result.getReturnValue()); });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Comment: Good point. Thanks. But replacing my init with a change handler doesn't change anything.

Comment: @RobertSösemann This worked in my dev org. Make sure everything matches up namewise.

Comment: If its async why do the fields get displayed instantely?

Comment: @RobertSösemann It appears *nearly* instantly (~1/10th of a second, it looks like). However, nearly instantly is not soon enough for init to see the data.

Comment: When I replace your change handler with <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c. loadChildData}" /> the Apex is called. With <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.parent}" action="{!c. loadChildData}" /> it doen't work.

Comment: @RobertSösemann For some Locker Service-related reason, you apparently can't just pass the object verbatim into a parameter, but instead need to construct a new object to pass in.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Adding var market = cmp.get("v.market"); and passing in market as param doesn't work eighter? Can you please extend you code examples to show that?

Comment: @RobertSösemann As you wish.

Comment: Wow, that is really cumbersome. Now it works.

Answer (score 3):

Okay!
So Here is what you are Missing here.
1. you can not send Sobject as parameter so break it into fields that you want to use.
2.You are not using  **recordUpdated="{!c.doInit}"** in **force:recoedData** That is why init works for first time and it gets null.
I created custom object Property and did this. Take a look

Component :

```
<aura:component controller="MyCtrl" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="property" type="Property__c" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

 <force:recordData aura:id="propertyService" 
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetRecord="{!v.property}"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.doInit}"
                  layoutType="FULL" />

 </aura:component>
```

jsController : which has a custom field named as beds__c

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
   var action = component.get("c.queryData");        
   action.setParams({
        beds: component.get("v.property.fields.Beds__c.value")
   });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);   
}
})
```

Apex Controller :

```
public class MyCtrl {

@AuraEnabled
public static void queryData(String prop) {

    System.debug('parent' + prop);
     // prop is not null
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like There is no method name **queryData** in your apex controller and The parameters name is also not same.

Comment: I  
That was just an error I introduced when I prepared my code for SFSE. I corrected the question.