# How to get OrderItems data in a Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, order

I have a Lightning component that operates on the Order detail page as a Lightning action. It retrieves the data for the current Order like so:

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  layoutType="FULL"
  targetRecord="{!v.record}"
  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
  />
```

That part works ok... except the returned data does **not** include the order items (products), only the primary record. I can't find any way to get the order items within the component. I tried:

```
<aura:attribute name="orderItems" type="OrderItem[]"/>
```

This generates an OrderItem array, but it's empty, even though the order *does* have items in it. I'm guessing it's not linked to the Order id, so it has no criteria for fetching the items - but cannot find any way *to* link it to the order id.

Any help with this would be highly appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once the order record is loaded, you need to query the related order item in your apex controller. Please find the below link of the similar issue:-

[Record passed from force:recordData to Apex controller method is null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188368/record-passed-from-forcerecorddata-to-apex-controller-method-is-null)